# How can I add persistent storage to my openshift s2i build to prevent downloading deps again on every build?

Tags: maven, openshift, openshift-enterprise

I have a Java app running on openshift and I am doing frequent builds using s2i as part of a CI pipeline. Since the build container is ephemeral, maven has to download all dependencies on every build, making it slow. How can I add persistent storage to my build so that the dependencies stick around between builds?

I'm using openshift container platform 3.9 and I have searched the documentation on builds and did not find anything about persistent storage.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#source-to-image-strategy-options

Comment: Search through the OpenShift blog and you will find various posts on the topic of speeding up Java builds. For example https://blog.openshift.com/improving-build-time-java-builds-openshift/